# How do I create a new WP admin color scheme?

Tags: functions, wp-admin, dashboard, css

[I followed this guide](https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-admin-color-scheme/), but idk if it doesnt work for WP 5.0+ or if im doing something wrong.

I added this to my functions.php and the css file is a copy of the Light Scheme.

```
 function additional_admin_color_schemes() {
 $theme_dir = get_template_directory_uri(); 

wp_admin_css_color( 'pro', __( 'Pro' ),
$theme_dir . '/wp-content/themes/astra-child/pro/colors.min.css',
array( '#E5E5E5', '#E5E5E5', '#3498DB', '#3498DB' )
  );
}
add_action('admin_init', 'additional_admin_color_schemes');
```

Comment: Check out this free plugin on WP.org [Admin Color Scheme](https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-color-scheme/). No need to do any code, you can specify your color scheme via CMS on your profile page.

Answer (score 4):

This code works with WordPress 5.2 and is correct.

You now need to go to your Profile and select it by going to
`Users` > `Your Profile` > `Admin Color Scheme`
select the scheme and save.

[image]

Edit: Adding updated code for your colors CSS file since you're using a child theme:

```php
function additional_admin_color_schemes() {
    wp_admin_css_color( 'pro', __( 'Pro' ),
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/wp-content/themes/astra-child/pro/colors.css',
        [ '#E5E5E5', '#E5E5E5', '#3498DB', '#3498DB' ]
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'additional_admin_color_schemes' );
```

Note here I removed the `.min` from the CSS file. I recommend you copy the non-minified CSS file over, so you can easily edit and customize the styles.

Comment: I did it, but nothing changes. Shouldnt the theme have the same color scheme as the light theme since I copied the light theme css? .When I activate it the styling is the same as the default color scheme. I tried to edit the file but nothing happens. I checked in the console that the stylesheet is running, but when I try to access the file in the url I get an 404.

Comment: What is the URLs to the stylesheet, and what is the URL you're testing?
Also, I'm confused. You say "Shouldnt the theme have the same color scheme as the light theme".  Yes it should. But then you say "When I activate it the styling is the same as the default color scheme". So what's the problem? It is the same... since you copied it.  Also, if you make changes, they may not show because the file is likely cached. But if you're getting 404 error, then the file doesn't exit, doesn't have the right permissions on-disk to be read, or you're testing the wrong URL.

Comment: I saw it now that I set the url wrongly. The url to the child theme is: /wp-content/themes/astra-child/pro/colors.min.css. I tried to set $theme_dir to /pro/colors.min.css but when I check the console it always looks in the parent theme. 

I made a test to add it to the parent folder but still it doesnt take effect. What I meant is that its loading the default theme, (dark), and not the light theme which I made a copy of.

Comment: I've edited the answer with the code correct for child themes - please note change I made by removing the `.min`. You can put the .min back if you want to continue to use the minified CSS.

Comment: This is not working at all, do anybody have done it please give solution for this